# I don't know why 'if' statement is true

Tags: python

This is my Python code:

```
funcName = 'anything'
if funcName.find("Start") > 0 or funcName.find("start") > 0 or 
funcName.find("Main") > 0 or funcName.find("main"):
    print 'success'
else:
    print 'fail'
```

The code output is success, but I think output must be fail.

Why is the output success?

Comment: It's because the `find` returns `-1` when it's not finding anything and `-1` is not evaluated as `False`, see doc here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Comment: This kind of error is harder to make if you avoid repeating yourself: `if any(funcName.find(x) > 0 for x in ["Start", "start", "Main", "main"]):`.

Comment: A clearer way to write this would be `if 'start' in funcName.lower() or 'main' in funcName.lower():`.  Or even better: `if any(name in funcName.lower() for name in ['start', 'main']):`

Comment: I think [funcName.find("start") > 0] is False, So my code to be [if False or False or False or False]. That state's result is False. But it recognize True. Why???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to check the last `find` call too - `-1` won't be automatically regarded as false.

```
if funcName.find("Start") > 0 or funcName.find("start") > 0 or funcName.find("Main") > 0 or funcName.find("main") > 0:
```

Comment: I think     'funcName("start" > 0' is to be '-1 > 0' and it's result is False. So my code to be 'if False or False or Flase or False'. But why is to be true and execute success statement??

Comment: See the last `if` statement in your code compared to mine. Yours is missing `> 0`, which is needed when using `find`.